# Not able to execute statements involving SET using cx_Oracle from python

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I am trying to use the SET keyword as I want to spool the output as HTML for a query

```
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(mode=cx_Oracle.SYSDBA)
curs = conn.cursor()
#curs.execute('set markup html on;');
curs.execute('set pages 0');
curs.execute(new_param);
curs.execute('update empolyee set job_status=\'Completed\' where job_id=' + str(new_id))
```

But I always get

```
 File "./scheduler_poll.py", line 22, in func_sql
    curs.execute('set pages 0');
DatabaseError: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option
```

What is the reason and how to do it?

Comment: It appears that you are trying to use SQL*Plus commands (`set markup` and `set pages`).  You can only use SQL*Plus commands in SQL*Plus (or some other front-end tool that supports some subset of SQL*Plus commands).  You generally cannot use SQL*Plus commands from application code.  Your code could potentially invoke a separate SQL*Plus executable and pass in a SQL*Plus script.  Or you could write the code to convert your results to HTML.